# Как перехватить звук из выходного устройства Windows?

Tags: c++, qt

Нужно, желательно средствами *Qt*, но можно с помощью и других *С++* библиотек, перехватить весь звук который издают приложения, как например это делает *Fraps*.

Comment: WinAPI, иначе никак, работать с микшером винды, ловить Мастер-Выход(аудиопоток).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

это называется loopback recording, [дублирующий вопрос на EnSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6685259/5006740) ссылка на пример там тоже есть

вкратце - используется Windows Audio Session API (WASAPI), вот конкретно про [loopback recording](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316551(v=vs.85).aspx)